# Latex : spacing of Figures inserted as Tables

Tags: tables, spacing, graphics

I have inserted 2 figures into my Latex document as a table, using a mini page, so that they are next to each other. When i turn it into a PDF document, the figures overlap. I would like to be able to create a "space" between the 2 figures so that they are a bit more apart. I think I am supposed to change the table format but i'm not sure how. 
Here is the code:

```
  \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{minipage}{190pt}
{\includegraphics[width=220pt]{depth3.pdf}}
\caption{figure1}
\label{fig:1}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{190pt}
{\includegraphics[width=220pt]{depth4.pdf}}
\caption{figure2}
\label{fig:2}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the size of each `minipage` is given by the `190pt`, and the graphics width is `220pt`.  The alignment of each minipage within the table is given by the `cc` (which means `c`enter `c`enter---i.e. center each column).

By adjusting these parameters you should be able to get the spacing you want.  It might help to use the size `\textwidth`, i.e.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{depth4.pdf}
  \caption{figure2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```